# how to convert hive table from text to parquet

Tags: hive, hiveql, parquet

When i try to convert my hive table form textfile to parquet i found that all float columns transformed to NULL.

NOTE: i'm using snappy compression for the two tables.

I try this configs but it dosnt work.

```
beeline -u "url"
    --hiveconf hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true 
    --hiveconf hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict
    --hiveconf hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict 
    --hiveconf PARQUET_COMPRESSION_CODEC=snappy 
    --hiveconf hive.optimize.sort.dynamic.partition=true
    --hiveconf hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=10000
    --hiveconf hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=1000 
    --hiveconf hive.mapred.reduce.tasks=600; 
-e "INSERT INTO TABLE a partition(a1, a2) select * from b ;"
```

Comment: i did not undrestand

Comment: Please add DDL(create table statements) for both tables.